# @JsonFormat Date field to localtimezone

Tags: spring, spring-boot-test

I have a field called expiredDate. The value of this field in the DB is: `2019-11-06 22:48:04`. I am using SpringBoot and I have defined the field in POJO as:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @JsonProperty("expiration_date")
    Date expirationDate;
```

When I retrieve the date I get the following: `2019-Nov-07 04:48:04`. My requirement is to get it in the following format: `2019-11-06T22:48:04.000Z`.

I have given the timezone='CST' but I dont want to mention the timezone. I want my program to identify the timezone and show the result.

If I dont give the @JsonFormat annotation, I get the result in long.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Change the format string to `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")` Also you probably do want to specify timezone or else the time will be wrong if your server is in a different timezone than the client...

Comment: thx, I did the same and its showing the time converted to UTC. Let me ask this: How can I show the date field the same value as in DB? The client should get the same value as in DB

Comment: You can't, both store the time as a numeric, and just display it as whatever the timezone is set to on the server, or manually set by you.